# Send signal from C to Java

Tags: java, c, signals

So I have this Java program that creates processes that run a certain C program on the terminal (unix), and I need to notify the Java program when something happens in the C program (before the termination). How can I do this? I know that I'm gonna need signals, but I don't have much experience on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This the changes I made to the java, after calling the process:

```
            InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<INPUT>");
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</INPUT>");
            int exitVal = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

I what I did in the C when I want to notify the java:

```
char buff[20];
size_t nbytes;
ssize_t bytes_written;
int fd;
strcpy(buf, "This is a test\n");
nbytes = strlen(buf);
bytes_written = write(1, buff, nbytes);
```

But after running it I only get:

```
INPUT
/INPUT
Process exitValue: 0
```

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904318/reading-a-substring-from-a-string-value as an example, it seems to do what you want, try it

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is reading your C program's stdout

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c.exe");
    InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
```

now C program can talk to Java program

Comment: Question is quite vague, but this is probably the way to go. One "gotcha" with this is flushing, which may default to "only when a very large buffer is full", when the C program does not have interactive console.

Comment: Right, it was just a hint where to look for an answer

Comment: Yeah, it's just very annoying if you don't know about it. You test the program from command line and everything works, then you execute it from the other program and get no output, and then comb your programs for a different kind of bug which is not there...

Comment: I edit the first post with the changes, but I get nothing. am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a socket using c program and send it to java socket server. You can search on goole to find out sample.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to communicate between a Java program and another program spawned by it, is using the FIFO streams that are set up when you launch a subprocess. So, for example, if you launched your subprocess using `Runtime.exec()` or using `ProcessBuilder`, you have an object of type `Process`. By calling its `getInputStream()` you can have access to the process' stdout.

In the native code, just print your signals out to stdout and they can be read by the Java process.

Comment: Yes I am using Runtime.exec() in the java. So I just use the write() function in the C prog?

Comment: Yes, `write` and then `flush` should do the trick. On the Java side, just do `read()` from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Signals with Java, but this is not the best mechanism.  I would look at using JNI, JMS, Socket, RPC or some other solution first.  The problem with signals is that it doesn't allow you to transmit much information and it's the easiest to get right or debug.

For more details on signal handling and Java

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/ (link dead)

http://ringlord.com/dl/Signals-in-Java.pdf