# Reading a substring from a string value

Tags: java, cmd

I wrote a Java command line application for Windows, and stored the result of that cmd in a string variable.

My question is: Is it possible to get a substring from that variable from where I had stored the output of the cmd?

I want to put a statement that creates an action if a substring is found in the cmd output string variable.

Here are the methods of the application class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    runWndCommand("ping 192.168.11.3");
}

public static void runWndCommand(String cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = runtime.exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", cmd });

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());

     while (reader.hasNext())
     {
        String r=reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(r);
     }
     p.waitFor();
 }
```

Comment: You can use the String class `contains()` method to search for a string inside of another string.

Comment: Usually you want text after keywords you are looking for e.g. the time a ping takes. I suggest using `indexOf` so you know where the text is.

Answer (score 1):

A quick example of how to use `contains()` as in your example:

```
String r = reader.nextLine();

System.out.println(r);

if (r.contains("abc")) {
    System.out.println("abc found");
} else {
    System.out.println("abc not found");
}
```

This will print `abc found` if `"abc"` is a substring within `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider java.util.regex.Pattern it is a more flexible way to test whether a string contains what you expect